# Why is there no AKAMAI tag in Here

Tags: discussion, tags

I am just wondering why don't we have any [akamai](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akamai) tag in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ . It is better if we have tag [akamai](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akamai) in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ for better convenience of everyone.
We only have tag [akamai](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akamai) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akamai but not in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are created *as they are needed*; we don't keep a stock of all possible tags just in case they ever get used.

It looks like someone has created that tag so all is good :)